# How to make PyCharm recognize a package not in PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, pycharm, package, pythonpath

I'm using PyCharm to do some maintenance on a Python program that was developed without an IDE. The program imports a package that I'll call zzz. Package zzz is in a directory named zzz, which is in a directory that I'll call xxx. Directory zzz contains an __init__.py file, but no zzz.py file.

Package zzz is not in PYTHONPATH, but the program gains access to it like this:

```
sys.path.append(<absolute path of directory xxx>)
sys.path.append('zzz/zzz')
import zzz
```

After the import I can float the cursor over the name of package zzz and see that its pathname is the absolute pathname of directory zzz.

But PyCharm flags the import statement as an error, presumably because it can't find zzz in the pre-runtime PYTHONPATH.

I tried adding the pathname of zzz to the project's content folders (Files > Settings dialog, Project > Project Structure page). I marked it as a source folder. PyCharm still flags "import zzz" as an error.

This makes it hard to tell when the program contains a real error! The "at least one error found" icon (an exclamation mark in a red circle) appears above the scroll bar, regardless. What can I do to make PyCharm recognize zzz as valid?

I should note that "reorganize the directories" is not a viable solution; nor is "permanently change PYTHONPATH." We have a dozen or so programs that use zzz and load it the same way; I don't have the authority to move it, and the person who has the authority would not be willing to do so. Nor would the programs' users be willing to change their PYTHONPATH to help me make PyCharm happy!

Comment: Write a batch file that changes PYTHONPATH and then launches PyCharm.

Comment: If the directory is in the project, right click it and mark it as a sources root.

Answer (score 0):

Preferences->Project Interpreter, select the gear icon, then select Show Path for Selected Interpreter and add the desired path

Comment: choma, I need a little more information to do this. "Preferences" doesn't correspond to any menu or menu command I can find. I think you're referring to the Project > Project Interpreter pane of the Settings dialog, opened by the File > Settings command. There's a gear on that pane, but it doesn't provide a "Show Path for Selected Interpreter" command. There's only "Add Local," "Add Remote," and "Create VirtualEnv."

Comment: Later: I looked at this again and found that I can open a list of pathnames by selecting the gear icon's "More" option. But I can't add the package to it. The existing values suggest that it only accepts EXE files, and the name of the dialog, "Project Interpreters," indicates that it is for specifying interpreters, not modules or packages! If I have read this correctly, you must have misunderstood my question; this feature does do what I need at all.

Comment: Alex, the directory is in the project, and is already marked as a sources root. Perhaps you can suggest another technique; this one does not do the trick.