# can't use VTK python PyCharm

Tags: python, vtk

I tried to import vtk library in my python project.

Im using PyCharm. python 3.8, vtk 9.0.0

When I tried to get access to vtk methods, but there are only :

```
vtk.vtk_m
vtk.key
vtk.vtkmodules_m
vtk.all_m
```

Nothing else!
What im doing wrong?

Comment: A few precision may be useful : how do you install VTK ? What does mean `there are only` ? Any error message to share associated to a failing code ?

Comment: i installed it on mac (brew install vtk) and also in PyCharm in venv as side package

Comment: Are you able to use vtk from external interpreter ? You can also check the VTK path and how to configure PyCharm : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48947494/add-directory-to-python-path-in-pycharm, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37335724/how-to-make-pycharm-recognize-a-package-not-in-pythonpath